# how to edit crontab with PHP shell_exec

Tags: php

I want to edit crontab from PHP script.

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($output);
            echo "</pre>";
```

This is returned.

```
MAILTO="admin@example.com"
*/2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron  > /dev/null
MAILTO=""
*/1 *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url 'https://www.example.com/referral/send_referral_email'
MAILTO=""
*/5 *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url ' https://www.example.com/members/send_notif'
MAILTO="admin@example.com"
*/2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron3 > /dev/null
```

One of the scripts `https://www.example.com/members/send_notif` should be running every five minutes but isn't.  I see there is a space before the https and i think that might be the cause.  How do i edit?  I haven't got access to cpanel, so i have to do from PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the output of crontab, make the required change in the variable and then write it to a file:

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
$find="' https";
$replace="'https";
$output =str_replace($find, $replace,$output);
$file="/path_to_a_file_which_is_writable/crontab.txt";
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

Then write the new content to crontab:

```
 shell_exec("crontab ".$file);
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't read that. I will edit my response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
# new crontab EDIT THIS
$crontab = '''MAILTO="admin@example.com"
*/2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron  > /dev/null
MAILTO=""
*/1 *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url 'https://www.example.com/referral/send_referral_email'
MAILTO=""
*/5 *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url ' https://www.example.com/members/send_notif'
MAILTO="admin@example.com"
*/2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron3 > /dev/null''';

# echo new cron into cron file
shell_exec('echo "' . $crontab . '" >> mycron')
# install new cron file
shell_exec('crontab mycron')
# delete cron file
shell_exec('rm mycron')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it.

```
$url = " https://www.example.com";
$new_url = "https://www.example.com";
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
$output = str_replace($url,$new_url,$output);
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.PHP_EOL);
echo exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');
```

Comment: If my response was helpful, could you please upvote it? I see the solution you found is exactly the same, just the variable names are different. Thanks.